# How to enable stacktrace react-native run-android command?

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, stack-trace

I'm running a react native project via the `react-native run-android`. But during the build it fails stating that `:react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources FAILED`. Which doesn't give much info, so I tried running with `react-native run-android --stacktrace` as suggested but that isn't a recognized command.

How can you enable stacktrace / verbose logging with `react-native run-android` command?

This is the detail of the error which is too short to figure out at build:

```
:react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: -12.542 secs
```

Package.json for reference:

```
{
  "name": "StarterKit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|tcomb-form-native|apsl-react-native-button,react-native-device-info|react-clone-referenced-element)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "verbose": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "html-entities": "^1.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "qs": "^6.3.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.9.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "git+https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-google-analytics-bridge.git",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.37.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "0.0.48",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "striptags": "^2.1.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.16.3",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.1",
    "invariant": "^2.2.2",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  }
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't have my laptop with React Native atm so I can't test it for you but check out this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-console-logs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@EricHua23's answer is basically correct, except that instead of running `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`, you should run `./gradlew.bat installDebug --stacktrace`, as this is the command that's actually run by `react-native run-android`. (and some of the errors you'd want to get the stack-trace for only occur in the installing/late-build portion, rather than the assembly portion)

Also, make sure you run it in the **android** folder. (so run `cd android` in the console before running the gradlew command)

Comment: I guess that's an useful response. Unfortunately I am so not-familiar with `gradle` that I don't know how to actually have the app running and the logs shown on my terminal. The command does install the app but doesn't run it interactively. I am probably missing the command that allows to run it.

Answer (score 5):

Try to build `react-native-device-info` separately with `./gradlew assembleDebug` and make sure `react-native-device-info` is all right. I have the same problems because of my network which is blocked and can not reach `jcenter`.

By the way, `--stacktrace` should be add as `gradle` parameters, I doubt `react-native` does not pass it to `gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

If running on Windows run following command in your project's root directory:

```
 1. cd android 
 2. gradlew.bat installDebug --stacktrace
```

Comment: following this process shows me "gradlew.bat: command not found"

Answer (score 1):

First go in your android folder and than run command ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace it will debug the gradle installation and shows if there any error.

1. cd android
2. ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use package.json file like this, for shortcut to shell commands, in my ViroMedia Sample App:

```
{
  "name": "ViroSample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "android": "react-native run-android --variant arrelease",
    "and_bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "gradle_build": "cd android && ./gradlew --stacktrace --info assembleRelease -x bundleArReleaseJsAndAssets",
    "gradle_install": "cd android && ./gradlew installArDebug --stacktrace --info",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-viro": "2.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I issue the following command from my project root directory (iMac bash shell):

```
yarn gradle_install
```

Please see the script block above for other shell commands.

> Note: in windows this is gradlew.bat.

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

From mac this will work

```
1. cd android
2. ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace
```

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to `react-native start`

This shows errors verbosely.