# Failed to install the following SDK components: [Android SDK Platform 26]

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am trying to configure Android studio for react so far every thing worked fine but whenever i run `react native run-android` it gives error something like this.

```
"Install Android SDK Platform 26 (revision: 2)" failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 26]
  Please install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 51.309 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

i thought i need to install Android SDK platform 26 (revision: 2) but it is not available in sdk manager so from sdk tools 26.0.3 but still its not working.
can anyone tell me where is the problem and how can i fix this.

Comment: run gradle--stacktrace

Comment: did you mean react-native run gradle --stacktrace ??

Comment: @AnubhavGupta ???

Comment: yes @aditya kumar

Comment: it says Unrecognized command 'run';

Comment: your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596358/how-to-enable-stacktrace-react-native-run-android-command

Comment: 2
down vote
accepted

Try to build react-native-device-info separately with ./gradlew assembleDebug and make sure react-native-device-info is all right. I have the same problems because of my network which is blocked and can not reach jcenter.

Comment: i don't know what this means

Comment: try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614510/android-studio-build-error-firewall-blocking-gradle-access-to-studio

Comment: still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179761/discussion-between-anubhav-gupta-and-aditya-kumar).